# Camel HeaderFilterStrategy CamelHttpQuery

Tags: filter, routes, apache-camel

I have the following route:

```
<route id="my-route">
   <from uri={{some.queue}}"/>   
   <to uri="bean:beanProcessor?method=processMethod"/>
   <to uri="{{a.nice.url}}?headerFilterStrategy=#myFilterStrategy"/>   
</route>
```

and this headerFilterStrategy:

```
<bean id="myFilterStrategy" class="org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultHeaderFilterStrategy">
    <property name="outFilter">
        <set>
            <value>camelhttpquery</value>
        </set>
    </property>
    <property name="lowerCase" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Inside the processor the CamelHttpQuery is set to

```
 CamelHttpQuery=first=465546&second=312863&third=0
```

I would expect because of "myFilterStrategy" that CamelHttpQuery will not reach the "a.nice.url" endpoint. However it does. How is this possible?

To mock the "a.nice.url" I have loaded another camel context with a route that uses a jetty endpoint. There I print the In headers and I see that CamelHttpQuery is there.

Comment: If want to filter the header of CamelHttpQuery, the default HttpHeaderFilterStrategy should work for you. It filters the message header which name starts with "Camel".

Comment: I simply want to understand why my implementation does not filter CamelHttpQuery. I also noticed that it does not filter the actual query parameters which are somehow put in the message. Is it because the CamelHttpQuery header is created inside BeanProcessor which is in the same route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Camel HeaderFilterStrategy is used to filter the message header when mapping it from the protocol header to camel message or from the camel message to the protocol header.

For the camel-http component, the camel message header can be mapped as the http header, but as the camel-http use the CamelHttpQuery to build up the request url, you can still get the Query parameter from the http request.

Comment: So basically you are saying that camel-http component uses CamelHttpQuery to build the http query before the filtering and on the other end Camel translates the incoming http query to CamelHttpQuery again. Same goes for the actual query parameters.